# Facebook Graph API: Getting all posts a user is tagged in even if the privacy setting is set to friends only

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Background:

I am using the Facebook Graph API to get every post that appears on a user's wall. To do this we have our user log in with Facebook and we ask for the `user_posts` permission from the user when he/she signs up. To get the posts we have been calling

`me/feed?fields=created_time,id,message,from{name,picture.height(48).width(48),id}&date_format=U&access_token={The User's Token}`

Question:

This returns all posts that appear on the user's wall **except** posts in which the user is tagged and the privacy setting is not `public`. How can I fetch these posts in which the user is tagged in but the privacy setting is set to `friends` or `friends of friends`?

Is it possible that this could be a bug?

The Facebook docs say:

> Your app needs user_posts permission from the person who created the
>   post or the person tagged in the post. Then your app can read:
>
> Timeline posts from the person who gave you the permission.
>
> The posts that other people made on that person Timeline.
>
> The posts that other people have tagged that person in.

I am having a hard time articulating the problem well so I will use my own Facebook account as an example. 1 out of the 3 most recent posts on my wall is a Post that I was tagged in. The post that I am tagged has a privacy setting of friends. The post I am tagged does not appear in the Graph API explorer output.

Here are the 3 most recent Facebook posts on my wall:

[image: The 3 most recent posts on my Facebook wall]

Here is the Graph API Explorer output:

[image: Graph API Explorer output]

Here are the permission on the token:

[image: Permissions]

Privacy settings for the post not included in the Graph API Explorer output:

[image: Post Privacy Settings]

Just to restate the main problem: the graph API only returns posts that a user is tagged in if it has a privacy setting of `public`.

Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Run your query in the `graph api explorer` in the test application. Everything is working fine. API 2.7.

Comment: @stdob-- I updated the post with screenshots from the Graph API Explorer and my personal Facebook wall. Does this help to clarify the question? Is there anything I can add to make the question more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. I reported it to Facebook. Here is the link to the bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/284611378567364 as of 8-3-16 at 10:20pm pacific it says bug confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all post's information if your app status show  live on  developers dashboard ( https://developers.facebook.com/).

you can fetch tagged post information also .To get all posts info we have been calling

> me/feed?fields=created_time,id,message,from{name,picture.height(48).width(48),id}&date_format=U&access_token={The User's Token}